# Smarty: Display a random sentence from array

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty template, that I want to display a random sentence on each reload. I could do it with this:

in php file:

```
$sentences = array('Hello you', 'Hi mate', 'Welcome');
shuffle($sentences);
$smarty->assign('sentence', $sentences[0]);
```

in template file:

```
<h1>{$sentence}</h1>
```

Is it possible to do all this in the template instead? Since this isn't exactly programming logic but more a presentation logic, i would like it all in the template like so:

```
<h1>{'Hello you', 'Hi mate', 'Welcome'| selectRandom }</h1>
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement smarty function selectRandom then :-)

```
{selectRandom(1, 2, 3, ...)}
```

Comment: Yeh, well, I hoped there was already some function to do that.

Comment: i don't think there is any more laconic way to do this. may be it's possible to use **only smarty builtin** functions but i bet it will be a long-long string with a lot of dirty hacks :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like this ([source](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16348&view=previous&sid=d44618a0f23c1dcdff67072c4e263004)):

> {assign var=randomindex value=$Images|@array_rand}
>
> <img src="./images/{$Images.$randomindex}" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt="Random Image" title="Random Image">